# Regular expression avoid htm tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Hi guys I would like to know if I can do a regular expression to avoid < and > in my text input.
I was thinking to use a regular expression to check first on the client. I just have this but I wonder how could I do it negative, this will match, but I need the inverse.
Thanks in advance!!!!

```
TextBoxRegularExpressionValidator.ValidationExpression = HtmlExpression();

private string HtmlExpression()
{
    return @"<[^>]*>";

}
```

For example if I enter in a text box this: <  script  > then fire the regular expression validator and tells that user can not type it because are not a valid characters.

Comment: I just want to validate on my client when user enter < and > characters, in general html open and close tags...

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is just escape any characters you don't want. For example, you can replace `<` with `&lt;` and then not have to worry about what the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, "<.*>");
```

Comment: I do want that the validator fire when type <whatever> if you know what I mean...

Comment: I am sorry...I don't fully understand the question. Can you elaborate (maybe with an example)?

Comment: @gpmurthy He wants it to match everything that's *not* between brackets, rather than matching everything that *is* between brackets.

Comment: Yeap you are right, do the inverse...not sure how to avoid user dont enter suspisious characters.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a regex you can use.

```
((?<=^)|(?<=>)).*?((?=<)|(?=$))
```

It has lookbehind for either the start of the line or the `>`, and ends when it reaches a `<` or the end of line.

Of course, it's generally not a good idea to use `Regex` to parse any generalized HTML, as HTML isn't solely comprised of nodes following this pattern.  Unless you know that your input is specifically of a subset of HTML/XML to which this is valid, you should use a proper parser.

Comment: What is the best practice to avoid user enter malignous characters??? Sorry but the regular expression didnt work :(